# Use of dimension time() in fortran

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

Can anyone help me decoding below code, as in what is the function of time()?

```
IF (TIME(1).EQ.0.0) THEN
      open (unit = 20, file = "C:\Temp\RANDOM.TXT")
```

Comment: Not part of the Fortran standard, so either an additional "builtin" (like [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gfortran/TIME.html) or [this one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-time-portability-routine)), or a part of your program. In the first case, it depends heavily on the compiler used, in the latter impossible to help you without seeing its implementation.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You really should try to search a manual of your compiler before asking https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TIME.html and check if your program (which we cannot se) does not contain some other definition. It is very likely it is defined somewhere in your code.

Comment: Or it could be an element of an array called `time`.  We need to see more context (code, compiler output) to be able to answer.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut this is part of UMAT subroutine of Abaqus where starting lines of codes are given below:                                                                             *USER SUBROUTINES
      SUBROUTINE UMAT(STRESS,STATEV,DDSDDE,SSE,SPD,SCD,
     1 RPL,DDSDDT,DRPLDE,DRPLDT,
     2 STRAN,DSTRAN,TIME,DTIME,TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,CMNAME,
     3 NDI,NSHR,NTENS,NSTATEV,PROPS,NPROPS,COORDS,DROT,PNEWDT,
     4 CELENT,DFGRD0,DFGRD1,NOEL,NPT,LAYER,KSPT,KSTEP,KINC)
C
 INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
C

Comment: @vipeshsingh And we were supposed to guess that?

Comment: @vipeshsingh You really have to [edit] the question and the the important information there.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Abaqus User Subroutines Reference Guide](http://dsk.ippt.pan.pl/docs/abaqus/v6.13/books/sub/default.htm), in section *1 User Subroutines -> 1.1 Abaqus/Standard subroutines -> 1.1.41 UMAT*. `TIME` is an array with two elements:

> TIME(1)
>
> Value of step time at the beginning of the current increment or
>   frequency.
>
> TIME(2)
>
> Value of total time at the beginning of the current increment.